# Sorting by string

Tags: sorting, symfony

This code is in Symfony2.
I have to sort documents by their names and later after dates. Firstly I have to display documents which have string in their names, for example 'aaa'. Later they should be sort by a date. Now I get record from base by Query Builder and in Order By I have set sorting by a date. Now how I can record with string, for example 'aaa' set to be first ? Is there any way in Query Builder to do that or I should later make something to set them first or maybe I should make it in a Twig file... ?

For example I have strings 'btaaa', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee' . String 'btaaa' should be first because it has 'aaa', my pattern. Rest of them should be sorted by date.

Comment: Are you wanting to sort by 2 things (date then string) or are you wanting to return the object and then sort after (not sure why this would be of use if it was all before the render)? If just by date then string you could just add another order by like... `->orderBy('**date**', 'ASC')->orderBy('**string**', 'ASC')`.

Comment: For example I have strings 'btaaa', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee' . String 'btaaa' should be first because it has 'aaa', my pattern. Rest of them should be sorted by date.

Comment: 'btaaa' would also be first because it starts with 'b' but I get what you mean (it would still be first if it was 'daaa'?). You might be able to create a hidden field with a regex just selecting the strings and then order by that field. Not sure how well (if at all) it would work though.

Comment: Yes, even the 'yaaa' should be first because it has 'aaa' pattern. I will try something like this you propose. If I will figure it out I will write you ;-)